# 3D visualization for marine navigation

Tags: 3d, bathymetry

Is there anyone who has some experience or knowledge on 3D visualization and/or GIS softwares capable of displaying 3D bathymetric data and 3D ship model together? Nearly all GIS softwares work with 3D data in grid format but I especially would like to learn whether it is also possible to put a 3D ship model on bathymetric model and dynamically visualize a ship's navigation by displaying its underwater sections.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Eonfusion could do this, this video and others on the website show similar tasks: 
http://www.eonfusion.com/applications/view_video_of_data_processing_and_analysis_for_rovauv_13400495/view_video_gallery_13400425

To actually put in the ship you can import COLLADA (and similar) models, but to animate you would need to replicate the model for each time step and map its changing coordinates to the time slider, a little tedious to do but not very hard.